# How to retrieve all rows with a date in this and the next week? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a `Tasks` table that contains `Date`, `Description` and `WorkerID` columns. I want to write a stored procedure that selects all tasks from this week and the following week. Can someone help me get to a solution please? I am not so good at this.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? "SQL" isn't a database engine. Answer may be specific depending on your DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If indexing (performance) isn't a concern then it's a simple expression if your week coincides with the SQL Server setup:

```
where datediff(week, getdate(), [Date]) between 0 and 1
```

The snippet below is another option that works with both dates and datetimes. It's possible to adapt it to work with any `@@datefirst` setting but I'm just going to assume that the setting matches with the start of week you're looking to report on.

```
where
       [Date] >= dateadd(day,  1 - datepart(weekday, getdate()), cast(getdate() as date))
   and [Date]  < dateadd(day, 15 - datepart(weekday, getdate()), cast(getdate() as date))
```

Comment: This won't show the ones in the following week, i tried changing 1 to 2 and 3 but still not

Comment: I had accidentally flipped the arguments. Try it again.

Comment: okay that works, except like the other suggestion, it doesn't return tasks on sunday next week, only till saturday, i wonder why

Comment: Run `select @@datefirst` and tell us what value you get.

Comment: I am very new to sql, not sure how to do anything really. I tried changing to select @@datefirst but when running my c# code to execute it i get error on Task.Date = (DateTime)datareader["Date"];

It might be too hard to help me when im so new to it

Comment: Better to run from a tool like SSMS. But try `select cast(@@datefirst as datetime) as [Date]`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you what you want (assuming Monday is the first day of the week, and that the DBMS is SQL Server):-

```
select * 
from Tasks
where [Date]
between
dateadd(dd,-(datepart(dw,[Date])-2),[Date]) --Monday of this week
and
dateadd(dd,13,dateadd(dd,-(datepart(dw,[Date])-2),[Date])) --Sunday of next week
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try this as soon as i can! it was SQL Server

Comment: I don't think your expression will work for Sunday. When you take the negative you really want the additive inverse modulo 7.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't select sunday next week. With my lack of understanding I tried changing 13 to 14 but that didn't do it, how should the code look then?

Comment: I also changed the 2. lines "-2" to -1 and -7 but see no difference in output

Comment: The problem that I had noted only happens when you run the query and the current date is a Sunday. Also if you have a datetime rather than a date type then you would have other problems. Is it cutting of Sunday at the same time as current time of day?

Comment: I run it as today (24th tuesday) and it returns me the tasks with data up until saturday (5th) not sunday